# Rollback whole dag run if one of the tasks fail in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have 2 tasks and dependency is set as

```
task1 >> task2
```

I want to rollback the sql statement in task1 which executes in snowflake if the sql statement in task2 fails. Is it possible to do this in airflow.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: Regardless of which database it runs on this question does not need Snowflake tag

Comment: What you are asking is to undo committed SQL transactions. Regardless of Airflow this is not a good design for ETLs. Don't commit to the DB changes that you are not sure about them. There is no Airflow workaround for this. If for some reason you must have this then write a "rollback script" place a branch operator that will check if task1 is succesful or not, in case it doesn't you can execute task3 with the rollback script.